# ExtJS: Binding an observable boolean property

Tags: extjs4

I have a view which contains some tabs (TabView).
Initially some tabs are disabled - they should only be enabled when a certain condition is met.

I'd like to implement it in the following way:

Create a TabViewModel which contains a boolean (observable?) property PersonSelected.
Create a TabViewStore
Bind the TabViewStore to the TabView

In my controller I would have an action method (e.g. onPersonSelected) which will should set the PersonSelected property to true.

What is the best way to bind the PersonSelected property to the View?
As my store would only contain on record, I feel that using the is a bit overkill. Can I do this without the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply subscribe to the `change` event of the UI element (checkbox? in your case). Am I missing something?

Comment: actually I would like to bind the property to the disabled config of the tabItem.. Is there a change event as well?

Comment: You mean you want to catch 'disable' event? I don't think you can do this. However UI element will not go disabled on its own - it's your code who is changing it, so you kind of know already when it's happening

Comment: No I actually would like to have it the other way round: When I update the bound (observable) model property, I would expect it to update the  disabled property in the tab. I don't know if this is possible in extjs: I'm just acustomed to this pattern from knockout.js and WPF.

Comment: There is no observable model fields in ExtJs. You need to do all this logic in the controller and view.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. At least I can stop looking and trying :)